# Specify newcommand to provide default argument to existing command

Tags: macros

I have an existing command, defined within a \newenvironment:

```
\newcommand{\param}[3]{\textbf{##1} & \emph{##2} & ##3 \\ }
```

That command on its own works fine.

What I want to be able to do is to alias this command for typical use cases.  The second argument to this command is a type, so I want something like:

```
\providecommand{\number}{}
\renewcommand{\number}[2]{\param{##1}{number}{##2}}
```

However, this gives the error: `Argument of \number has an extra }.`

This error appears even if the `\number` command is never used.

What would the cause of this be?

Comment: The idea is fine _per se_, but `\number` is a TeX primitive, so redefining it is probably causing an issue with a place where the original version is expected.

Comment: Aha, that appears to be it.  I realised that \number was an existing command, but I thought that if I redefined it within the \newenvironment, it wouldn't cause any problems (as the scope would be limited).  It seems I was wrong on that!  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joseph said, redefining `\number` is a bad idea, It's particularly self referential here as `\newcommand` (and `\providecommand` etc) all use `\number` to process the `[2]` optional argument that specifies how many arguments the command has. This normalises away any space and TeX constructs that expand to a number and exposes the literal digit that is needed to construct the `#1#2` primitive TeX `\def` syntax.

```
\long \def \@yargdef #1#2#3{%
  \ifx#2\tw@
    \def\reserved@b##11{[####1]}%
  \else
    \let\reserved@b\@gobble
  \fi
  \expandafter
    \@yargd@f \expandafter{\number #3}#1%
                           %%%%%%%
                           %%%%%%%
}
```